# Host couchdb on heroku

Tags: heroku, erlang, couchdb

I would like to host couchdb in a free heroku instance. I found here on stackoverflow an answer and it says, it is possible to host erlang code on heroku.

Now I had the idea, to host couchdb on heroku. But it doesn't work. Here is my try:

```
.>git clone https://github.com/apache/couchdb
.git
Cloning into 'couchdb'...
remote: Counting objects: 55066, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1582/1582), done.
remote: Total 55066 (delta 2125), reused 3094 (delta 1808)
Receiving objects: 100% (55066/55066), 26.56 MiB | 1.34 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36610/36610), done.
Checking out files: 100% (338/338), done.

.>cd couchdb

.\couchdb>explorer .

.\couchdb>git add .

.\couchdb>git commit -m "added proc file"
[master 9c6da00] added proc file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 Procfile

.\couchdb>heroku create couchdb-cl --region e
u --buildpack https://github.com/archaelus/heroku-buildpack-erlang
Creating couchdb-cl... done, region is eu
BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/archaelus/heroku-buildpack-erlang
https://couchdb-cl.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:couchdb-cl.git
Git remote heroku added

.\couchdb>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Imanuel/.ssh/id_rsa':
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 40416, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12588/12588), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40416/40416), 17.50 MiB | 562 KiB/s, done.
Total 40416 (delta 27271), reused 40371 (delta 27237)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:couchdb-cl.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:couchdb-cl.git'
```

But it fails to push.

Here is the Procfile:

```
web: erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin -noshell -boot start_sasl -s reloader -s couchdb
```

Anyone an idea or maybe another option to host a couchdb instance for free? :)

Comment: did figure out how to fix that?

Comment: Sadly no, I am currently having a project where I could use this fairly well..

Answer (score 1):

Heroku built their polyglot platform, which currently supports Ruby or Rails, Node.js, Java, Spring or Play,    Python or Django, Clojure and Scala ([source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar#polyglot-platform)).

All other languages including Erlang are built using *build packs*. You can find [Erlang build pack on github](https://github.com/archaelus/heroku-buildpack-erlang). Run the instructions from README and you should be good to go.

Comment: Do you still get the same error message or different one?

Comment: Like in my post, cause I used the exact buildpack, could you try it maybe? :)