# How do I setup Apache CouchDB to run on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, couchdb

I have a node.js RESTful API that is using Apache CouchDB for it's NoSQL database. I am new to Heroku and just deployed my API to Heroku instance. However, the startup failed because it couldn't connect to CouchDB. I have researched how to setup CouchDB on Heroku but haven't found anything that works.

I found this buildpack but it doesn't exist any longer: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/aindeev/heroku-buildpack-couchdb

I found this stack overflow post but there doesn't look to be a solution provided: [Host couchdb on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554373/host-couchdb-on-heroku)

Can someone help provide me with some instructions on how I can host couchdb on heroku?

Comment: Looks like there is another [heroku-buildpack-couchdb](https://github.com/creativegeekjp/heroku-buildpack-couchdb) which might be useful. Also your CouchDB can be hosted on [cloudant](https://cloudant.com)

Answer (score 2):

If you are at the step of creating an app you can do the following

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/creativegeekjp/heroku-buildpack-couchdb.git
```

and thereby create the app with the couchdb buildpack installed.

however if you already have the app what you can do is

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL="https://github.com/creativegeekjp/heroku-buildpack-couchdb.git" -a YOUR_APP
```

The -a YOUR_APP is optional, you probably don't need it considering you're probably in a folder you've initialized as a heroku app when you add the buildpack.

Or the easier

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/creativegeekjp/heroku-buildpack-couchdb.git
```

after which you have to run

```
git push heroku master
```

to deploy your buildpack